# ClobberError when trying to install the nltk_data package using conda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, nltk

I am trying to install nltk_data package to my environment natlang using conda by giving the following command:

```
(natlang) C:\Users\asus>conda install -c conda-forge nltk_data
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for nltk_data located at 
C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\pkgs\nltk_data-2017.10.22-py_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 
'lib/nltk_data/corpora/propbank/frames/con.xml'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared 
path.
packages: conda-forge::nltk_data-2017.10.22-py_0, conda-forge::nltk_data- 
2017.10.22-py_0
path: 'lib/nltk_data/corpora/nombank.1.0/readme'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared 
path.
packages: conda-forge::nltk_data-2017.10.22-py_0, conda-forge::nltk_data- 
2017.10.22-py_0
path: 'lib/nltk_data/corpora/nombank.1.0/readme-dictionaries'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared 
path.
packages: conda-forge::nltk_data-2017.10.22-py_0, conda-forge::nltk_data- 
2017.10.22-py_0
path: 'lib/nltk_data/corpora/nombank.1.0/readme-nombank-proposition- 
structure'
```

I am working on Anaconda 3, python version 3.6.5, windows 10 enterprise.
Can someone please tell me why this error is occurring and how can I fix it.

Background: I originally wanted to use punkt in one of my programs using the code lines:

```
import nltk_data
nltk.download()
```

This would open the nltk downloader and after installing all the packages including punkt, on further running the program I would still encounter the  following error:

```
 LookupError:
 Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.
 Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

 [31m>>> import nltk
 >>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

I tried rerunning the nltk.donwload() and nltk.download('punkt') a couple of times with no change. So then I decided to simply install the nltk_data package to my environment based on the assumption that if I install the package to the env itself, I won't have to use the nltk.download function to use punkt.

Summarizing, I have the following two questions:

1. If I install the nltk_data package to my evn, do I still need to use the nltk.download function in my code? If yes, how do I resolve the lookup error?
2. If installing to the evn is enough, then how do I resolve the clobber error?

(ps: I apologize if this sounds stupid, I am very new to machine learning and working with python in general.)

Comment: Try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`nltk_data` repository](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data) is a collection of zipfiles and xml meta data. Usually, it is not installation through packaging tools such as `conda` or `pip`.

But there is this utility from `conda-forge` that tries to install the `nltk_data`, https://github.com/conda-forge/nltk_data-feedstock

To use it, on the terminal/command prompt/console, first add the `conda-forge` channel:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Then you shouldn't need the `-c` option, and just use:

```
conda install nltk_data
```

Please try the above and see whether that get rids of the ClobberError.

---

This error is requesting you to download a specific nltk dataset call `punkt`:

```
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

Running `nltk.download()` without specifying which specific dataset you want to download will call up a tkinter GUI which normally wouldn't be possible if you are accessing your machine remotely without a GUI.

If you're unsure of which resource you need, I would suggest using the `popular` collection.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('popular')
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering 2 que first- there have been similar issues all across windows machines. Its better to use the ntlk.download() function if you want to use punkt or a similar module. 
1) The lookup error can easily be resolved. It was because of a typo. Instead of

```
import nltk_data
```

it should be

```
import nltk.data
```